# Only include odd elements in array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Not sure why this code does not work edit* it is supposed to return only odd elements in an array

```
function findOdd(A) {
  var arr = [];

  for (var i=0; i<A.length; i++){
    if(arr.indexOf(A[i]) == -1){
      arr.push(A[i]);
    }
    else {
      arr.splice(A[i],1);
    }
  } 
  return arr;
}
```

For test case findOdd([20,1,-1,2,-2,3,3,5,5,1,2,4,20,4,-1,-2,5]) should return 5. However it returns [20, -1, 3, 5]. Any idea as to why this doesn't work as I think it should? Thank you.

Comment: can you explain why it should return 5?

Comment: You never check to see whether elements are odd or not.

Comment: do you mean the odd numbers, or the odd iterations of the array items?

Comment: or the number that appears an odd number of times? `5` appears 3 times in the example array, which is an odd number of times. the other numbers appear twice.

Comment: yeah, seems to be find duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change this line

```
arr.splice(A[i],1);
```

to

```
arr.splice(arr.indexOf(A[i]),1); //remove it from index of this element since splice is taking index rather than element itself.
```

**DEMO**

```js
function findOdd(A) {
  var arr = [];

  for (var i=0; i<A.length; i++){
    if(arr.indexOf(A[i]) == -1){
      arr.push(A[i]);
    }
    else {
      arr.splice(arr.indexOf(A[i]),1);
    }
  } 
  return arr;
};

var output = findOdd([20,1,-1,2,-2,3,3,5,5,1,2,4,20,4,-1,-2,5]);
console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also do the job very efficiently as follows;

In this particular case the `hash` object produced by the `.reduce()` looks like

```
{ odd : { '1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0, '5': 3, '20': 0, '-1': 0, '-2': 0 },
  even: { '1': 2, '2': 2, '3': 2, '4': 2, '5': 0, '20': 2, '-1': 2, '-2': 2 } }
```

Ond the `Object.keys()` part collects the required information from the `hash.odd` sub object.

```js
function oddMany(a){
  var hash = a.reduce((h,n) => h.odd[n] ? (h.even[n] = h.odd[n] + 1, h.odd[n] = 0, h)
                                        : (h.odd[n] = h.even[n] + 1 || 1, h.even[n] = 0, h), {odd:{},even:{}});
  return Object.keys(hash.odd).reduce((r,k) => hash.odd[k] ? r.concat(k) : r ,[]);
}

var arr = [20,1,-1,2,-2,3,3,5,5,1,2,4,20,4,-1,-2,5];

console.log(oddMany(arr));
```